# WP All controltemplates are invalid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a very odd issue that ive had for a while now, I opened my project one day in visual studio and 2/3 of my xaml had blue wavy lines, it said invalid xaml and distorted some of the layout but everything built fine and the layout returned to normal once built and running on a phone, so i just ignored it. Now i want to update my layout but anything that has a control template does not work, so i deleted everything in the xaml so i had just an empty grid, i designed a slider in blend and copied and pasted the code and im still getting the exact same problem. i opened a new project and it copied fine from blend.